# Alignment error in React Bootstrap Form

Tags: reactjs, alignment, react-bootstrap

I am using react-boostrap form with following code:

```
import React  from 'react';
import {Form, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';

class FirstForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Form">
                <Form horizontal>
                <FormGroup controlId="email">
                    <ControlLabel className="FormRow">Email</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="E-mail Id"/>
                </FormGroup>
             <FormGroup controlId="user">
            <ControlLabel className="FormRow">user name</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="User name"  />
             </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <FirstForm/>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

export default FirstForm;
```

In .css file,

```
.FormRow {
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

But the output looks as:[image]

This is what I have added. Remaining are obtained from default react-app. Can someone help to format it?

Comment: It's pretty hard (not to say impossible) to see the error. Could you provide an live example where it is not working

Comment: I did not get any error messages. Output looks like what I posted :((

Comment: Could you provide a not working example, where we can see the actual html css and javascript? Looks like something is missing, but the screenshot doesn't say what. To see whats wrong we need more code.

Comment: something like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers or jsfiddle or something similar

Comment: probably you are missing the `<Col>` elements/components: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-horizontal

Comment: You are not using `<Col>` element as per react-bootstrap document https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-horizontal

Comment: Using <Col> did not give a proper form. Still mis-aligned. Other best way to create a form?